# React Action Cable Provider not updating url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

i am using react-actioncable-provider for chat module and passing url with user id  to provider. on application load use rid will be null and when successfully login user id updated and provider will re-render. i do not know why this happening. after url updated provider still requesting with null id my code is below as..

```
const App=(props)=>{
      let userId = localStorage.getItem("userId");
      const [url,setUrl]=useState(`${enpoint}/cable?id=${userId}`);
      useEffect(() => {
     if(props.data&&props.data.user){
      setUrl(`${enpoint}/cable?id=${props.data.user.user.id}`);
    }
  },[props.data]);`enter code here`
  console.log("url",url);
  return (
      <ActionCableProvider url={url}>
      // other components
      </ActionCableProvider>
```